# Создание проекта в Visual Studio на С# для 32-битной Windows XP

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-xp

Как в Visual Studio создать проект на С# для 32-битной Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

1. Убедиться, что установлен Targeting Pack для .NET 4.0. Его можно установить, отметив соответствующую галку в инсталляторе студии на вкладке "Компоненты".
2. В свойствах проекта выбрать целевой платформой .NET 4.0.

На машины с XP для запуска вашей программы нужно будет поставить Service Pack 3 и [распространяемый пакет .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=17718).